# Generate new variable based on multiple variables with NA

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have 2 vars, each can take 0, 1, NA. The new_var I wish to create should fulfill following conditions:

If any of var1 and var1 is 1, then new_var = 1,
If non have a value of 1, then any of var1 or var2 is 0, then new_var = 0,
If non have a value of 0, then new_var takes NA

```
var1 <- c(1, 0, NA, 1, 0, NA, 1, 0, NA)
var2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)

df <- data.frame(var1 = var1, var2 = var2)
```

`c(1, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)`

should be the result.

I have tried:

```
ever_fun <- function(x, y){
  ifelse(x == 1 | y == 1, 1, 
         ifelse(x == 0 | y == 0, 0,
                ifelse(is.na(x) & is.na(y), NA, 0)))
}



df <- df %>% 
  mutate(new_var = mapply(ever_fun, var1, var2))
```

Yet the case of var1=0 var2=NA yield NA instead of 0. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Using *pmax*:

```
pmax(var1, var2, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1]  1  0 NA  1  0  0  1  1  1
```